# Should whitespace in the markup in a cshtml file be meaningful?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, forms, layout

I'm seeing some strange behavior while trying to add a basic markup for a login form in an ASP.Net MVC 4 project. Here's the portion of my cshtml file in question:

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-right">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="span2" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="span2" />
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

That markup renders great in my theme:

[image]

However, if I change it to this:

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-right">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="span2" /><input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="span2" />
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

It starts rendering like this:

[image]

I noticed this because I was trying to take a simple form from a foundational theme and implement it with `Html.BeginForm()`. This results in markup that's all on one line though, so I'm seeing that squeezed look.

I can probably just correct it with some css, but I'm curious if anyone knows why I'm seeing this behavior. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML, any white space is treated as a single space.  For example:

```
<div>TestTestTest</div>
```

Will have no spaces in between each word.

```
<div>Test Test Test</div>
```

Will have a single space.

```
<div>Test     Test
Test</div>
```

Will look the same as the second example.

The same applies to input tags:

```
<!-- No spacing -->
<div>
    <input /><input />
<div>

<!-- Line break converts to a space -->
<div>
    <input />
    <input />
<div>

<!-- Really big font -->
<div style="font-size: 120pt;">
    <input />
    <input />
<div>
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ht6fm/).

What's even more screwy is *some* browsers will give you a `TextElement` in the DOM between your two `<input>` tags.  E.g.

```
<div id="foo">
   <input />
   <input />
</div>
```

The element `foo` will have 3 child elements (an input, a text element, another input) - where as:

```
<div id="foo"><input /><input /></div>
```

Will have 2 child elements.  This has screwed me up before when I was trying to refer to a child element by its index and it was working on IE and not Chrome (Pro-Tip: Never do this)

You are correct that you should use CSS to specify exactly how you want elements laid out.  Assign your `<form>` tag a class, and define how you want child elements in that class to flow, as well as margins, padding and spacing between each one.

Comment: Yes, I understand how whitespace should work within a div. However, it seems that I'm getting some unexpected behavior with whitespace in between two elements.

Comment: There's no difference.  You literally have a *space* character between your two input tags.  When you remove the line break, there's absolutely no elements in the DOM between the two inputs.

Comment: In other words, what you're seeing between the two inputs in the first screen shot is text.  Crank up the font size if you don't believe me.

Comment: @atcrawford whitespace between elements set to `block` or `inline-block` is honored.  Input elements are `inline-block`.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, especially the JsFiddle demo! I've definitely learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no it shouldn't.... but apparently it IS... so.  I would first check both version in Firebug and see what you can find there.  Also check that you have a Doctype defined in you Layout.

Comment: Also, just sayin' ... may as well /> on your inputs. :)

Comment: I've not been able to find any differences with Firebug, though I'm certainly no expert with it. Also, I've got this doctype set: `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

This is just a sample form, but I'll go ahead and add the /> for posterity... thanks :)